# Stop for a couple of seconds a Progress Bar

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jprogressbar

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I'd like to make a `JFrame` with multiple progress bars (`JProgressBar`) with different speeds.

### The Problem

When the value of one progress bar is 25, 50 or 75, it's supposed to stop the current progress bar for 2 seconds.
As of now however, `Thread.sleep()` will stop the entire app.

```
Timer timer;

ActionListener listener;
listener = new ActionListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    int delta = 1;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        counter += delta;
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
            if (counter < min || counter > max) {
                delta *= -1;
            }
            counter = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, counter));
            jjProgressBar.setValue(counter);
            jjProgressBar2.setValue(counter);
            jjProgressBar3.setValue(counter);
            if (jProgressBar.getValue() == 25 || jProgressBar.getValue() == 0 || jProgressBar.getValue() == 50 || jProgressBar.getValue() == 75 || jProgressBar.getValue() == 100) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Sim1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
timer = new Timer(100, listener);
timer.start();
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: Can't understand what you want to do. As I see you have 1 main and 3 secondary progress bars. When the value of the main progress bar is 0, 25, 50, 75 or 100 you want to stop only this progress bar for 2 seconds. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can always [multithread](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032e/index.html) your progress bars and `Thread.sleep()` them individually.

`Thread.sleep()` does not really make sense in your particular context, since it's only one monolithic application controlling what should be an MVC/multithreading application.

Comment: can you give me a example

Comment: [click here for a complete walkthrough in theory and practical use](https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java)

Comment: @Antonio feel free to read up on [what to do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)